# Upgraded emacs and polymode (poly-markdown+r-mode); now can't edit .Rmd files

Tags: emacs, polymodel

I have been happily using polymode in emacs for editing Rmd files for many years. Then something broke in emacs (maybe the FastX3 config?), so the admins updated emacs from 24 to 27 for me. Now emacs works nicely but not polymode and no Rmd editing.
I installed `polymode`, `poly-markdown`, `poly-R`, `poly-markdown` from melpa, but I can't get poly-markdown+poly-r to work. I had installed the packages by hand a long time ago -- some parts of my `.emacs` file date back to the 1990s. So I created a minimal `.emacs`:

```lisp
 (setq package-enable-at-startup nil)

(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/elpa"))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
(setq package-check-signature nil)
(setq use-package-verbose nil)
(setq package-enable-at-startup t)
(setq package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize t)

;;; Markdown mode
;; (autoload 'markdown-mode "markdown-mode" "Major mode for editing Markdown files" t)
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.markdown" . markdown-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.md" . markdown-mode) auto-mode-alist))

;;(require 'polymode)
;;(require 'markdown-mode)
(require 'poly-R)
(require 'poly-markdown)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd" . poly-markdown+r-mode))

(require 'package)

(require 'ess-site)
(require 'ess-rutils)
```

Now when I load a `.Rmd` file the screen comes up in Fundamental mode.
Anyone have any ideas?